# Security Update requires installation every time I launch TorBrowser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Every time I launch the Tor Browser it tells me "There is a security update available for the Tor Browser Bundle. Click here to go to the download page"

I've downloaded it twice and replace the file 5+ times, can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: First off I have a quick question for you, did you download the current version from http://www.torproject.org? If not, you may have gotten a compromised version of tor. Click this [link](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) for information on verifying your version of tor or just re-download tor from the tor project site.

Comment: You should not unpack over the old version.
Export bookmarks in a backup folder, then delete old release, then unpack the new release.
This makes sure you have all files updated, and nothing old that can intervene with the new release.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me also until I noticed that the update didn't overwrite the current install but installed itself alongside.

If you look in  your "Tor Browser" directory you may find another "Tor Browser" sub-directory, that's where the new version is (you can double check with the files date).